# Check the linear independency of a set of cycles in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, linear-independence

As I am reading wikipedia and some material:

> A basis for cycles of a network is a minimal collection of cycles such that any cycle in the network can be written as a sum of cycles in the basis.

Some other material also point out the cycle basis need to be linear independent and span the graph.

Given a graph (V,E). Say I already have a set of cycles C. How can I check the linear independent between these cycles?

$$C = {C_0, C_1, \cdots }$$
$$C_0 = {e_0, e_1\cdots}$$

For the example below, from my understanding, in the left it is cycle basis, but on the right it is not because there's linear dependency on the 2 cycles.

[image]

Is there any simple algorthim to do this, or any material I should look into for to this?

Comment: Number edges of the graph, write the cycle as binary vectors, where there is a $1$ if ed the cycle contains the corresponding edge, else $0$. Then you can study the independence of your cycles by studying the linear independence of the vectors over $GF(2)$. In your two examples, the selected cycles are independent but if you take the three possible cycles, then there is a linear dependence since the sum of two cycles gives the third cycle.

Comment: @caduk Thanks, you mean even the right one is linear independent though they share some edges, but they are linear independent in the cycle space.  I think I got it and the calculation, I'll try and see, thanks.

Comment: Yes, both share edges, but that's not what defines dependent cycles. Here, on the left, both cycles have an edge that is not present in the other one, so this can be seen a family of row echelon vectors, hence these must be independent.